# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have recently started learning programming by watching CS50 course. I am currently on the introduction of Python. Everything was done by me in accordance to that video-course. By writing simple code I get an issue unlike my lecturer does.

Here it is:

```
answer = input("What's your name?")
print(f"hello, {answer}")
```

Issue I have got:

```
File "hi.py", line 2
    print(f"hello, {answer}")
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would be sincerely grateful for your answer!

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It's probably a version that predates f-strings, which were introduced in Python 3.6 if memory serves.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.16

Comment: Python 2 has been end-of-life for over two years. I strongly suggest you install Python 3. The current release is Python 3.10.

Comment: I am grateful for support, Chris!

Answer (score -1):

hello you can't use the print function in the Variable
so the right way to write this is

```
answer = input("What's your name?") 
print(f"hello, {answer}")
```

[image]

Comment: ...isn't this exactly the same code as in the question?

Comment: I have just copied, inserted the code suggested and it still does not work. So I am up to download the newer version of Python.